# Dropdown button won work

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I cant seem to get the dropdown to work. Just made a dropdown with HTML and CSS codes. Here it is: Ive been trying to fix it but I just cant find the right fix, it would never show up whenever I hover over the button. This is for a school project.

```css
.dropbtn1 {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.horizontal-navbar #main-horizontal-navbar-links-dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.horizontal-navbar li:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: white;
}
#main-horizontal-navbar-links-dropdown > button {
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="horizontal-navbar">
  <li id="main-horizontal-navbar-links-dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn1">NEWS</button>
  </li>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#"> AFINEX PARTNERS WITH SPECS FOUNDATION </a>
    <a href="#"> SPECS FOUNDATION REACHES 10,000 BENEFICIARIES </a>
    <a href="#"> EYE TRAIN Featured in Canadian Nationwide TV Broadcast</a>
    <a href="#"> MESSAGE FROM SPECS FOUNDATION PRESIDENT </a>
    <a href="#"> WORLD SIGHT DAY 2015 </a> 
    <a href="#"> NEXT TRAIN ON ITS WAY </a>
    <a href="#"> EYE TRAIN FEATURED IN NEWSPAPER</a>
    <a href="#"> ROTARY CLUB OF SAN MARCELINO </a>
    <a href="#"> GRATITUDE TO CANADIAN DONORS</a>
    <a href="#"> YOUNG VISION </a>
    <a href="#"> SAMAR MISSION 2014 </a>
    <a href="#"> CHILDREN AND AGED ORPHANS MISSION 2014 </a> 
    <a href="#"> AMBULATORY SURGICAL CLINIC AT ST.JOHNS OPENS </a>
    <a href="#"> EYE TRAINING - THE MAKING 1 </a>
    <a href="#"> EYE TRAINING - THE MAKING 2 </a> 
  </div>
  <li class="main-horizontal-navbar-links"> <a href="#" target="_blank"> PROJECTS </a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-horizontal-navbar-links"> <a href="#" target="_blank"> SERVICES </a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-horizontal-navbar-links" style="border-right: none;"> <a href="#" target=""> BENEFITS </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What does doesn't work mean? What's happening? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- Remove the class `.horizontal-navbar` on line 23 of the CSS file.
- The `</li>` after the `<button>` is wrong, set it after the `</div>` of `.dropdown-content`

Test and tell us!

Comment: I had a problem with the dropdown showing off at the side of it, after following this the dropdown ended up right below where I wanted it to be! Thank you to you and sir Vincent up there!!

Answer (score 2):

`.dropdown-content` is not a child of `#main-horizontal-navbar-links-dropdown`, it's a sibling so you have to change your selector to this to make it works :

```
    .horizontal-navbar #main-horizontal-navbar-links-dropdown:hover ~ .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdef6twL/2/)

**Doc:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors